# How to decide whether a power series is algebraic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, lo.logic, cv.complex-variables

I vaguely recall that there is a theorem stating,  a power series is algebraic iff the coefficients of the series is automatic over every finite fields.

Could anyone give the article or the theorem ? Thanks.

Actually it sounds that the theorem is just an instance of compactness theorem of first order logic.

Comment: Something like the initial remarks [**here**](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/133301/MathSlov_50-2000-1_5.pdf)?

Comment: "here" in Benjamin's comment refers to: *Allouche, Scheicher, Tichy, Regular maps in generalized number systems, Mathematica Slovaca, Vol. 50 (2000), No. 1, 41--58*

Comment: @BenjaminDickman it seemingly is not the article, I recall one author is a Chinese.

Comment: Are you just asking about **Christol's Theorem**? If so, you received this in an answer to your own MO question back in 2014: [**165847**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165847).